# Matching last end of month's value on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, left-join

I have basically 2 tables: Funds and Ratings.

```
create table Ratings
(
 RatingDate date,
 CustomerNumber int,
 CustomerName varchar(50),
 rating varchar(50)
 
);

insert into Ratings (RatingDate,CustomerNumber,CustomerName,Rating) values
( '20200131', 783,'Danny','7+'),
( '20200229', 783,'Danny','5'),
( '20200331', 783,'Danny','5'),
( '20200430', 783,'Danny','1'),
( '20200130', 331,'Isabelle','3'),
( '20200229', 331,'Isabelle','3-'),
( '20200330', 331,'Isabelle','2'),
( '20200430', 331,'Isabelle','2'),
( '20200131', 481,'Denise','5'),
( '20200229', 481,'Denise','5-'),
( '20200331', 481,'Denise','6'),
( '20200430', 481,'Denise','6');

select * from Ratings;

RatingDate | CustomerNumber | CustomerName | rating
:--------- | -------------: | :----------- | :-----
2020-01-31 |            783 | Danny        | 7+    
2020-02-29 |            783 | Danny        | 5     
2020-03-31 |            783 | Danny        | 5     
2020-04-30 |            783 | Danny        | 1     
2020-01-30 |            331 | Isabelle     | 3     
2020-02-29 |            331 | Isabelle     | 3-    
2020-03-30 |            331 | Isabelle     | 2     
2020-04-30 |            331 | Isabelle     | 2     
2020-01-31 |            481 | Denise       | 5     
2020-02-29 |            481 | Denise       | 5-    
2020-03-31 |            481 | Denise       | 6     
2020-04-30 |            481 | Denise       | 6     


create table funds
(
 Date_of_Credit date,
 CustomerNumber int,
 CustomerName varchar(50),
 CreditSuffix int,
 CreditAmount money
);

insert into funds (Date_of_Credit,CustomerNumber,CustomerName,CreditSuffix,CreditAmount) values
('20200204', 783, 'Danny',1000,15000),
('20200309', 331, 'Isabelle',1100,27000),
('20200303', 783, 'Danny',1001,25000),
('20200220', 481, 'Denise',2000,17000)
;

select * from funds;

Date_of_Credit | CustomerNumber | CustomerName | CreditSuffix | CreditAmount
:------------- | -------------: | :----------- | -----------: | -----------:
2020-02-04     |            783 | Danny        |         1000 |   15000.0000
2020-03-09     |            331 | Isabelle     |         1100 |   27000.0000
2020-03-03     |            783 | Danny        |         1001 |   25000.0000
2020-02-20     |            481 | Denise       |         2000 |   17000.0000
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2fb4ec114e5b091adb3e5a7f382b0f1)**

I need to match each customer's credit transaction with last month's rating before credit('s date). Expected result is as below:

[image: Result]

However,

as you can see my code (in the link), result is not relevant to what i expected. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there always is one rating at the very last day of each month, you can use `eomonth()`:

```
select f.*, r.rating
from funds f
left join ratings r 
    on  r.CustomerNumber = f.CustomerNumber
    and r.RatingDate = eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, f.Date_of_Credit))
```

To make this work with your sample data, you need to change February 28th, 2020 to February 29th (2020 is a leap year).

On the other hand, if you want to bring the latest rating of last month (regardless of its actual date), then you can use a lateral join:

```
select f.*, r.rating
from funds f
outer apply (
    select top (1) r.*
    from ratings r
    where 
        r.CustomerNumber = f.CustomerNumber
        and r.RatingDate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(f.Date_of_Credit), month(f.Date_of_Credit), 1))
        and r.RatingDate <  datefromparts(year(f.Date_of_Credit), month(f.Date_of_Credit), 1)
    order by r.RatingDate desc
) r
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bdd408b24d901bb62123739b36e6a06a)** - both queries yield:

```
Date_of_Credit | CustomerNumber | CustomerName | CreditSuffix | CreditAmount | rating
:------------- | -------------: | :----------- | -----------: | -----------: | :-----
2020-02-04     |            783 | Danny        |         1000 |   15000.0000 | 7+    
2020-03-09     |            331 | Isabelle     |         1100 |   27000.0000 | 3-    
2020-03-03     |            783 | Danny        |         1001 |   25000.0000 | 5     
2020-02-20     |            481 | Denise       |         2000 |   17000.0000 | 5
```

Comment: it looks like, works like charm. I have added my notes your suggestions, and it will help my future progress, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL query :

```
 select t1.*, t2.Rating
    from funds t1, Ratings t2
    where t1.CustomerNumber = t2.CustomerNumber and month(t2.RatingDate) = month(t1.Date_of_Credit)-1
```